# Unable to use aggregate function in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregate

Is it possible to use aggregate function after the find function in MongoDB? I want to query a document and then aggregate according to find result.

`db.movies.find({"runtime":30},{runtime:1,year:1,"imdb.rating":1,"imdb.votes":1,type:1,"tomatoes.viewer.rating":1,"awards.wins":1}).limit(3).aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$runtime",award_wins:{$sum:1}}}])`

After executing this command I am getting an error that, aggregate is not a function,

`E QUERY    [js] TypeError: db.movies.find(...).limit(...).aggregate is not a function :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it as below,you can't run aggregate along/after find

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{$match:{"runtime":30}},
{$project{runtime:1,year:1,"imdb.rating":1,"imdb.votes":1,type:1,"tomatoes.viewer.rating":1,"awards.wins":1}},
{$limit:3},
{$group:{_id:"$runtime",award_wins:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: Do upvote and mark as answer if the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate()` cannot be used along with `find()`. You should use corresponding aggregate methods to execute the query.

**Edit:**
Try this out.

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{$match:{"runtime":30}},
{$project:{runtime:1,year:1,"imdb.rating":1,"imdb.votes":1,type:1,"tomatoes.viewer.rating":1,"awards.wins":1}},
{$limit:3},
{$group:{_id:"$runtime",award_wins:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more with an example?

Answer (score 1):

To invoke the aggregate function, you must use db..aggregate instead of find. Try the below:

```
db.movies.aggregate({"runtime":30},{runtime:1,year:1,"imdb.rating":1,"imdb.votes":1,type:1,"tomatoes.viewer.rating":1,"awards.wins":1}).limit(3).aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$runtime",award_wins:{$sum:1}}}])
```